# How can I solve the errors when building apk from unity game?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

[image]

After clicking Build button to create apk file of the game I got Gardle build failed, I solved that problem but after another attempt to create onother apk file I got a message said there are many errors that are shown in the pictures, How can I solve these errors shown in the attached pictures in this question?

I want a solution for bulding apk file of my game in unity

Comment: what does the second error say exactly? Sounds like something about major version etc but we can't see all of it

Comment: something like you picked v53 and only upto 52 is supported